# How to convert current date time to a specific format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a date column in pandas and it has dates like this:

```
Fri Sep 18 2020 21:57:21 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
```

How do I convert it to a format like this :

```
2020-09-18 21:57:21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format of your column is consistent, might be easier to just slice it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"time": ["Fri Sep 18 2020 21:57:21 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)"]})

print (pd.to_datetime(df["time"].str[4:21]))

0   2020-09-18 21:57:00
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Wow. this is cool. How does it work? I don't get it.

Comment: You can use [`str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html#pandas-series-str-slice) to obtain the valid parts of string, and cast the column to datetime64 using `pd.to_datetime`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try stripping the unnecessary text:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['text'].str.extract('^(.*) GMT')[0])
```

Output:

```
0   2020-09-18 21:57:21
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
print(x.strftime("%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S"))
```

more info here:
https://stackabuse.com/how-to-format-dates-in-python/

Comment: ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'Fri Sep 18 2020 21:57:21 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)')

In [ ]:

Answer (score 0):

Start by dropping the day and the last part GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time).

then you could apply the function right to the column so the values are changed

```
df['time']=df['time'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```